# Intellij unable to find file from classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij is unable to find a file on the classpath with the following java statement:

```
 URL fileUrl = TestClass.class.getResource("/data.xlsx");
```

The variable fileUrl is null;

[image]

Comment: I guess you must add before your package name **catalogs** like this:
TestClass.class.getResource("/catalogs/data.xlsx");
I'm not sure if it works due to the structure of the project

Comment: As per the snapshot data.xlsx seems to be inside the catalogs folder.. please verify and see how you can access the resources folder and its sub folders

Comment: I changed the statement as follow :  TestClass.class.getResource("/catalogs/data.xlsx");  And now the URL is set.   Thanks  Edgar.

Comment: Check this answer for the ways to load resource from classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above.
I changed the statement as follow :

> TestClass.class.getResource("/catalogs/data.xlsx");

Now the URL is set.